# How can the compilation properties be determined in a procedural macro?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-proc-macros

I'm working on a procedural macro that does a lot of work that can slow down compilation considerably. The work done does not effect the semantics of the function; that is, if given the same set of arguments, the returned value is does not change depending on whether the macro is applied.

In an effort to make the edit-comp-test loop quicker, I would like to make the macro a no-op depending on conditions that relate to how the crate is being compiled. I would like to be able to determine two properties in particular:

1. Why the macro is being executed: Build/Run, Documentation, Testing
2. Whether the macro being executed for optimized builds.

Cargo [exposes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-build-scripts) the optimization level to build scripts (through environment variables `OPT_LEVEL` and `PROFILE`) but does not expose the mode (Build, Documentation, ..). However, none of this information seems to be exposed to procedural macros at all.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can write a build script that makes the values of the environment variables available during compilation, either with `rustc-env=VAR=VALUE` or with `rustc-cfg=FEATURE`. See the [documentation on build scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) for more details.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Tunneling build script variables by redefining them is something that I had completely overlooked. Thank you for mentioning it. Tunneling env vars solves problem 2 but doesn't solve problem 1 unfortunately. Since it's still helpful, please feel free to post it as a partial answer and I'll gladly upvote it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I have another open question where your solution would be an acceptable answer, so please also feel free to post an answer there so I can accept it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215463/what-is-a-suitable-place-to-store-procedural-macro-artifacts-so-that-they-are-cl