# Is it possible to create a custom derive that would prevent cycles between types at compile time?

Tags: rust

For example, I want the following code to not compile because `Foo` can point at a `Bar` which can point at a `Foo`.

```rust
#[derive(NoCycles)]
struct Foo {
    k: u32,
    p: Option<Rc<Bar>>,
}

#[derive(NoCycles)]
struct Bar {
    s: Option<Rc<Foo>>,
}

#[derive(NoCycles)]
struct Baz {
    s: String,
}
```

If `Bar` was changed to have an `Option<Rc<Baz>>`, compilation should succeed because there is no way for `Foo` to point at a `Foo`.

Comment: The problem of recursive structure is that their size is infinite, that not related to runtime or compile time problem. Just infinite size is impossible.

Comment: In this case, the size is finite - there's an indirection through Rc.

Comment: I'm sure that a procedural macro could be written that applied to the whole module and that checks, using graph theory, that there are no loops, but I don't think it exists, yet.

Comment: No, because there is [no way to store state within Rust's procedural macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52910783/155423).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't need state if you applied the procedural macro to the whole module (assuming it contains all types relevant for cycle detection). Sounds like a pretty complicated solution though, and writing genuine proc-macros that get it right in every case can be tricky

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no experience with writing procedural macros, but I would try to generate a "parallel universe for the `NoCycle` versions". I.e. for each struct `Foo` that should participate in `NoCycle`, there would be a "parallel" struct `Foo_NoCycle` that is only used for cycle detection.

Now the idea: The struct `Foo_NoCycle` would be automatically generated from `Foo`, and its members would have the `NoCycle`-parallel types of the members in `Foo`. I.e. the following struct

```
struct Foo {
    k: u32,
    p: Option<Rc<Bar>>,
}
```

would have the parallel `NoCycle` struct:

```
struct Foo_NoCycle {
    k: u32_NoCycle,
    p: Option<Rc<Bar>>_NoCycle, // <- not real rust syntax
}
```

As you see, the above - simpfy appending the suffix `_NoCycle` - does not lead to valid rust syntax. Thus, you could introduce a trait that serves as a bridge between "normal" and `NoCycle`-structs:

```
trait NoCycleT {
    type NoCycleType;
}
```

Its usage - showcased for `Foo_NoCycle` - would be like this:

```
struct Foo_NoCycle {
    k: <u32 as NoCycleT>::NoCycleType,
    p: <Option<Rc<Bar>> as NoCycleT>::NoCycleType
}
```

Generating a `Foo_NoCycle` from a `Foo` should be doable by a macro.

Now comes the trick: You tell rust that for `u32` the corresponding `NoCycle`-type is `u32`, while `Rc<Bar>` has `NoCycle`-type `Bar`:

```
impl NoCycleT for u32 {
    type NoCycle=u32;
}
impl<T: NoCycleT> NoCycleT for Rc<T> {
    type NoCycle = T::NoCycleType;
}
```

This way, the `NoCycle`-types lead to real circular types, preventing compilation.

For your example, the `NoCycle`-structs would look like this:

```
struct Foo_NoCycle {
    k: <u32 as NoCycleT>::NoCycleType, // == u32
    p: <Option<Rc<Bar>> as NoCycleT>::NoCycleType, // == Bar_NoCycle
}
struct Bar_NoCycle {
    s: <Option<Rc<Foo>> as NoCycleT>::NoCycleType, // == Foo_NoCycle
}
```

Substituting the types shows:

```
struct Foo_NoCycle {
    k: u32,
    p: Bar_NoCycle,
}
struct Bar_NoCycle {
    s: Foo_NoCycle,
}
```

This way, the compiler sees that `Foo_NoCycle` and `Bar_NoCycle` form a circular type dependency that cannot be compiled.

It's not a solution that works without some effort to define `NoCycleT` for base types, and to define `NoCycleT` for things like `Box`, `Rc`, `Arc`, `Vec`, `Mutex`, etc. However, I guess the compiler would inform you about missing `impl`s so that you can just implement `NoCycleT` for types actually needed.