# Using Rust procedural macros to create a event system (with listeners registered at compile-time)

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use Rust's procedural macros to create an event system that builds a list of events and listeners at compile time. I'm looking to avoid any runtime registration, since events may need to be called hundreds or thousands of times a second.

I currently have two procedural macro attributes set up (listener and event):

```
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn listener(_attributes: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // attribute is attached to a function
    // write name of function to file
}

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn event(_attributes: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // ??
}
```

The goal is to use these two procedural macros to generate an interface similar to the following:

```
#[listener]
pub fn someListener(event: &EventA) { ... }

#[listener]
pub fn anotherListener(event: &EventA) { ... }

#[event]
pub struct EventA { ... }
```

The source code above would generate the following:

```
impl EventA {
    pub fn call(&self) {
        someListener(&self);
        anotherListener(&self);
    }
}
```

Which could then be used to do something like this:

```
fn foo() {
    let event = EventA { ... };
    event.call(); // will pass &self to "someListener" and "anotherListener"
}
```

I've been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910783/is-it-possible-to-store-state-within-rusts-procedural-macros) about storing state in between multiple procedural macro uses (and [the related issue on github](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44034)), which suggested using a tmp file*. I use this to generate a list of all functions that have the "listener" attribute attached to it, and look at the arguments to determine what the listener function is looking for.

The issue I am running into is that the event macro, which is responsible for creating an event type (which is simply a type that has an "event.call()" function that passes &self to all functions marked with the "listener" macro), needs to be generated *after* all the listener macros are evaluated (so it is aware of all of the listener functions). From the links above, this does not seem to be possible to do directly. As a workaround, I have an additional crate, with dependencies ensuring that it will run after the all the procedural macros are evaluated. The crate dependency structure looks something like this:

1. event crate (which defines listener and event macros)
2. main crate (which uses listener and event macros)
3. event build crate (which has a list of listeners and events from main, and can then build event functions)

Since the event build crate is built after the main crate, I believe if it provides a build script, that build script will run after the main crate is compiled (and therefore all listener procedural macros are evaluated). It will then have a fully working list of the listener functions.

As far as I can tell, I believe I have up to this point working. The problem I am running into is connecting the listener functions to the "event.call()" function. The "main" crate will be responsible for both providing the listeners, as well as calling the "event.call()" function -- and yet, this function will not be defined until the "event build" crate, since the event listeners are not known until then.

I have a C++ background, so my initial thought was to try and forward declare the "event.call()" function. If I could declare the "event.call()" function in the "main" crate, and then provide a definition for it in the "event build" crate, the dependencies would be resolved by the linker, and everything should be okay. I ran into some issues with this, however -- from what I can tell, it looks like "extern" is intended for Rust's FFI (i.e. to allow interoperability between Rust and other languages, such as C). I'm not sure how to use the extern keyword to link functions between Rust crates when the crate where the function is defined needs to be a dependency of the crate where the function is declared (and used).

The only other workaround I could think of would be to have the "event" crate declare an "extern C" function (i.e. extern_eventa_call), have the "event build" crate define that function *in C*, where the definition is just a call to the "event.call()" function defined in the "event build" crate.

```
extern void impl_eventa_call(); // declared in C, defined by Rust "event build" crate

void extern_eventa_call() { // declared in Rust "event" crate, defined here (in C)
    impl_eventa_call();
}
```

While I believe this would work, it feels extremely convoluted. Is there a simpler way of implementing the event/listener pattern in Rust, in a way that adds little to no overhead? If not, are there any problems with the steps I have listed?

---

*Storing state between procedural macros runs into issues with incremental compilation (where procedural macros are not called again if the item they are attached to does not need to be re-compiled during an incremental compilation), but I am ignoring that for the time being.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to avoid runtime registration? What overhead are you trying to avoid, the overhead of looping over a list of listeners?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I'm more concerned about the reduced ability for Rust to optimize the function calls (mainly inlining, though I would guess that hiding calls behind function pointers would reduce LLVM's ability to make other state based optimizations). If there are hundreds or thousands of event calls per second, and, for example, 10 listeners for each event, that would result in thousands to tens of thousands of extra function calls a second.

Comment: Have you benchmarked it? Does a runtime system underperform? Have you considered other options, such as splitting processing across threads, or batching up events?

Comment: I don't mean to be annoying. It's just, as you say, this is a convoluted setup. It's worth double checking whether you've already considered and ruled out other easier options.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I'll admit that I haven't run any benchmarks yet to see exactly how a runtime system compares in terms of performance. I'd like to explore a compile-time solution first, just because I am looking to optimize this as much as possible, but if that looks out of reach I'll definitely explore a runtime option as a solution. I am going to parallelize as much as possible (some of the events will be bound to a thread, such as those with OpenGL resources). I haven't considered batching just yet (it will depend on ordering requirements), but I'll keep it in the back of my mind -- thanks!

Comment: Not at all! I'm always glad to consider anything I might've missed (it's hard to improve otherwise!).

Comment: @User12345 Can you show the expected generated code?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Sure, I've updated the post to clarify

Comment: How can the main crate create the events if it doesn't know about them?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm not sure I follow? The main crate will create the EventA type, as well as the someListener and anotherListener listener functions. The event build crate, which is built after main, will generate the event.call() function, which can then be called from the main crate using an extern declaration, and having the linker resolve everything at the end.

Comment: Where is `EventA` declared, and where is its `call()` method declared?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman EventA is defined in the main crate. call() would be declared in the main crate (by the procedural macro) but would not be defined until the event-build crate, which would have the full list of events and listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go through the C ABI. `extern "Rust"` will work as well.

Other than that, if you insist on this architecture, I don't think there is something better you can do.

---

Declaring/defining a function using `extern "Rust"`:

```rust
// declare.rs
extern "Rust" {
    #[link_name = "declare_symbol"]
    pub fn declare_symbol();
}

pub fn testFunction() {
    unsafe { declare_symbol(); }
}


// define.rs (can be in different crate, must at least be in a different module than declaration)
#[export_name = "declare_symbol"]
pub extern "Rust" fn declare_symbol() {
    println!("Test");
}

// main.rs
// import declare_symbol() declaration
use declare::*;
/* import declare_symbol() definition
Rust complains about this being an unused import, but removing this import results in an undefined 
symbol (aka unresolved external) linker error. 

It looks like a crate must be imported at least once for it to be included (though it does not have
to be the module providing the definitions; importing/using another module in the same crate seems
to be fine as well).
*/
use define::*;

fn main() {
    testFunction();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to declare a function in one rust crate and define it in another? I've been able to declare the function using the #[link_name = "test_symbol"] attribute, but I'm not sure how to define a symbol; using the link_name attribute on the definition provides a warning ("attribute should be applied to a foreign function or static") and ultimately results in a linker error.

Comment: @User12345 `extern "Rust" { #[link_name = "..."] fn foo(); }`.

Comment: I've been able to use the link_name attribute to declare a function, but I'm not sure how to define it. I've tried providing a public function with the name given to the link_name attribute, but the linker fails with an unresolved external error.

Comment: Did you define it like `#[link_name = "..."] extern "Rust" fn foo() { ... }`?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. I get the previous warning "warning: attribute should be applied to a foreign function or static", followed by a linker error.

Comment: @User12345 My bad, `link_name` is for the import. For the export use `export_name`.

Comment: I've been able to resolve the linker error when the function declaration and definition are in the same crate, but when one crate provides the definition and other the declaration I get another linker error. I've checked the library exporting the symbol with dumpbin, and it looks like the symbol is present in the static library, but it's not found by the linker when the final binary is built. 
`#[export_name = "test_symbol"]
pub extern "Rust" fn test_symbol() { println!("Test"); }
#[link_name = "test_symbol"]
extern "Rust" { pub fn test_symbol(); }
`

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by importing the module where the function was defined, which makes sense in retrospect but I wouldn't have thought of otherwise. I've updated the answer to include a minimal example.